# How to compress algorithm in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, algorithms

I have written one algorithm in a beamer class by using a package `\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}`. It is taking the whole slide, I have tried to fit it into a small `minpage` but it is not working.

Is there any way to compress an algorithm in a beamer class. I can't share my algorithm.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 


\section{Section no.1} 
\frame{\frametitle{dwd}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} : A graph $(G)$\;
\textbf{Decide} : Is $G$ a random ? \\
\vspace{0.3cm}

If $X$ then stop and play and dance random \;
$S = \{g \in G \}$\;
Pick sdy $g \in P  $\;
Find n elemen. If  exits  then returno   ``Not sonian ''\;

\If{$X$}{
   Compute a lower and upper $L$ of $X$ in $G$;\\ 

    \If{$X$ exists and is fumbling lelal -grou}{

     return $zZ$\;
     }
}

 \Else{
     return  ``Not truein life''\;
  }

 \caption{Algorithm}
 \label{algofinite}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I will not able to share more of my code sorry.

Comment: The content of your algorithm does not matter, you could just make up some random algorithm that demonstrates your problem. The important point is to show use a small but compilable latex document that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a smaller fonts size to fit the algorithm into the frame. If `\small` is not enough and you are really desperate, try `\foototesize`, `\scriptsize`, `\tiny` or `\Tiny`

Some other comments:

- you don't need to load the `xcolor` package with beamer
- remove the `center` environment. It has no effect on content that spans over the whole text width, like your algorithm and just adds even more vertical spacing around which makes your problem worse
- instead of `\frame{}` better use the `\begin{frame}....\end{frame}` syntax

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

%\date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{dwd}

\begingroup
\small
%\begin{center}
%\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} : A graph $(G)$\;
\textbf{Decide} : Is $G$ a random ? \\
\vspace{0.3cm}

If $X$ then stop and play and dance random \;
$S = \{g \in G \}$\;
Pick sdy $g \in P  $\;
Find n elemen. If  exits  then report   ``Not sonian ''\;

\If{$X$}{
   Compute a lower and upper $L$ of $X$ in $G$;\\ 

    \If{$X$ exists and is fumbling lelal -grou}{

     return $zZ$\;
     }
}

 \Else{
     return  ``Not truein life''\;
  }

 \caption{Algorithm}
 \label{algo6}
\end{algorithm}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{center}
\endgroup

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]